# pip install django-import-export read timed out

Tags: python, django

I am trying to using django-import-export to populate my models with excel files. However, when I do `pip install django-import-export`, I get this following error

```
C:\Users\Billy Somers\webapps>pip install django-import-export
Collecting django-import-export
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed 
out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django-import-export/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None))
after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django-import-export/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None))
after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django-import-export/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None))
after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django-import-export/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None))
after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django-import-export/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-import-export 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-import-export
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the poor condition of internet connection.
May be you can fix this by using a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your are able to access pypi.org from browser over https. Also check if any port blocking at your firewall level.

If that doesn't work upgrade pip version then try to install. Do check on pypi that this distribution is present over there.